# Is it possible to store different kinds of structs into a flexible-length array?

Tags: c

Let's say we have two struct types as follows:

```
struct A {
    int a;
}

struct B {
    int b;
    int c;
}
```

Would it be possible to initialize a flexible-length array to contain instances of *both* A and B using designated initializers, e.g:

```
<sometype> my_array[] = {
    ((struct A){ .a = 10, }),
    ((struct B){ .b = 1, .c = 5, }),
};
```

And since I need to know the type of elements in the array, a way to put some char before the structs would be nice too. :)

I know this looks terribly broken, but I am trying to pack some bytecode-like data structures together and this looks like an elegant way to define them (well, with the help of some macros at least).

**Edit**: To clarify a few points:

- Dynamic allocation is not an option
- Neither are unions - I want the elements to occupy *exactly* the space needed by their type
- "Variable length array" in the question could have been misleading - the exact denomination would be "flexible length array", according to http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Zero-Length.html. The example code is ideally how I'd like it to look like.

So what I'd basically like is to be able to pack some arbitrary, structured data into a memory area that is allocated in the .data segment of the binary. I do not need random access to elements, just to pack the data from structs - the use of a flexible length array in my example is because this construct seems to be the closest from what I want to achieve. But the declaration could be anything else that does the job (except assembler, I need to retain C portability).

Comment: C doesn't have variable length arrays.

Comment: have yuu tried to use pointer and malloc...

Comment: @tjameson yes it does; see 6.7.6.2p4.

Comment: @ecatmur - I guess I read `variable length arrays` as `dynamically resizable arrays` or something. Oops...

Comment: Anyway the questioner's code doesn't *use* VLAs. What C doesn't have is "arrays, not all of whose elements are the same size", and I think that might be what the questioner was hoping for by saying "variable-length array".

Answer (score 5):

The best way for this would be to use unions. You could define all your types within a `union`, including this union and the `char` you wanna you for defining *what* is the actual type into a `struct`.

```
struct TypesAB {
    char type;
    union {
        struct {
            int a;
        } A;
        struct {
            int b;
            int c;
        } B;
    };
};
enum {
    TypeA,
    TypeB
};
```

With this `struct`, you can define your array, and then set the elements.

```
struct TypesAB array[10];
array[0].type = TypeA;
array[0].A.a = 10;
array[1].type = TypeB;
array[1].B.b = 1;
array[1].B.c = 5;
```

Note that the memory layout will make you loose some space if your `A` and `B` types are not the same length. Indeed, with the above definition, `struct TypesAB` will be defined with a `sizeof` large enough to hold the larger of the A or B, plus the char. If you use it as a A, then the memory space that would have been used for the `c` member is *lost*. The same memory space is used for the `a` member of `A` and the `b` member of `B`.

Comment: Sorry, I should have stated in the question that unions are not an option (exactly because of the loss of space that you mention). I am aware of this solution and am actually trying to do better in terms of memory footprint. Note that I don't need random access to elements, so the difference in size is not a problem.

Comment: In that case, there's nothing the C compiler can do for you. (In an array, all elements have to be the same size.) You'll have to use a blob of memory (some `char []`) and to iterate over it: reading the type char, and interpreting the data depending on the type, before finding a new type char, ...

Comment: Yep, I am aware that's how I will have to read that data - and that way of doing is fine. What I'd like to do is construct it in a compact and readable manner from C code. Actually I have an implementation that relies on structs in exactly the same fashion as you describe, I just want to make it more compact.

Comment: @Gnurou I'm afraid you are out of luck for you want too much: no malloc, no unions, easy syntax (and of course easy handling if possible). There is always need for a compromise - usually size (data packing) vs. speed (simple addressing) vs. readability (convoluted code to read packed data). Have you evaluated these well indeed?

Comment: @peterph I did - I am aware that alignment issues might pop up if things are not done properly, but I want to be able to save space when one structure of the sequence if much larger than the others (unions would make all instances of the biggest possible size). I'm surprised there is no elegant way to do that in C...

Comment: @Gnurou C is basically just a higher level assembly language, comapred to e.g. C++ it has much less abstraction. The elegant way is using memory allocation, but you ruled that out.

Comment: @peterph memory allocation is ruled out because this is static data I want to define at compile-time. Even if I wanted to allocate a buffer using malloc, I would still need the data to put in it. :)

Comment: @Gnurou If you know this much in advance, why not defining several arrays and assigning them directly and then you could have another array, that would point to the ones holding the data, i.e.: `type1[n1] = { ... }; type2[n2] = { ... }; type3[n3] = { ... }; types[n1+n2+n3] = { &type1[0],  &type2[0],  &type1[1],  &type1[2],  &type3[0],  &type3[1], ... };`? That would be a sort of compromise between dynamic allocation and packing the data tightly.

Comment: @peterph indeed, but at the same time I am looking for a straightforward way to define the data - having references all around is not handy. :) I could also go with a linked list, since sequencial access is not needed. Maybe that would be the best compromise.